# Prove that the vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k \operatorname{span}R^n$ if and only if $[v_1]_B,[v_2]_B,\ldots,[v_k]_B \operatorname{span}R^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

From section on **Change of Basis**

[image]

$\longrightarrow$ Assume the vectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\operatorname{span}R^n$, we must show that $[v_1]_B,[v_2]_B,\ldots,[v_k]_B\operatorname{span}R^n$.  We can write the vectors in $R^n$ as linear combinations of the coordinate vectors $[v_1]_B,[v_2]_B,\ldots,[v_k]_B$.

This is as far as I can get.  I have trouble proving things, I don't know how to.  I can't seem to prove any of the exercises I am faced with.  Are there any strategies to learn proofs?

Comment: Assume they do not form a basis (ie there is a null linear combination), then prove that B is not a basis.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure you are clear on definitions.

> "The vectors ${\bf v}_1,{\bf v}_2,\ldots,{\bf v}_k$ span ${\Bbb R}^n$" means: for every vector ${\bf w}$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$ there exist scalars $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k$ such that
>   $$\lambda_1{\bf v}_1+\lambda_2{\bf v}_2+\cdots+\lambda_k{\bf v}_k={\bf w}\ .$$

> The coordinate vector of ${\bf v}$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$ with respect to the ordered basis $B=\{{\bf b}_1,{\bf b}_2,\ldots,{\bf b}_n\}$ for ${\Bbb R}^n$ is the vector
>   $[{\bf v}]_B=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ such that
>   $${\bf v}=x_1{\bf b}_1+x_2{\bf b}_2+\cdots+x_n{\bf b}_n\ .$$

Next you will need a result about the connections between coordinate vectors.

**Lemma**.  If $B$ is an ordered basis for ${\Bbb R}^n$ and ${\bf v}_1,{\bf v}_2$ are vectors in ${\Bbb R}^n$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are scalars, then
$$[\lambda_1{\bf v}_1+\lambda_2{\bf v}_2]_B
  =\lambda_1[{\bf v}_1]_B+\lambda_2[{\bf v}_2]_B\ .$$

**Proof**.  Write $[{\bf v}_1]_B=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $[{\bf v}_2]_B=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$.  By definition this means that
$${\bf v}_1=x_1{\bf b}_1+\cdots+x_n{\bf b}_n\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  {\bf v}_2=y_1{\bf b}_1+\cdots+y_n{\bf b}_n\ .$$
Therefore
$$\lambda_1{\bf v}_1+\lambda_2{\bf v}_2
  =(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2y_1){\bf b}_1+\cdots
    +(\lambda_1x_n+\lambda_2y_n){\bf b}_n$$
and so
$$\eqalign{[\lambda_1{\bf v}_1+\lambda_2{\bf v}_2]_B
  &=(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2y_1,\ldots,\lambda_1x_n+\lambda_2y_n)\cr
  &=\lambda_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+\lambda_2(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\cr
  &=\lambda_1[{\bf v}_1]_B+\lambda_2[{\bf v}_2]_B\cr}$$
which proves the result claimed.  An almost identical proof shows that the same relationship holds for any linear combination of $k$ vectors.

Now we can begin the proof that you need.  Note that it is an "if and only if" statement, so there are two things to prove.

First suppose that
$$[{\bf v}_1]_B,\ldots,[{\bf v}_k]_B\quad\hbox{span}\quad {\Bbb R}^n\ .
  \tag{$*$}$$
We have to prove that ${\bf v}_1,\ldots,{\bf v}_k$ span ${\Bbb R}^n$.  So, let ${\bf w}$ be in ${\Bbb R}^n$; then $[{\bf w}]_B$ is also in ${\Bbb R}^n$.  From $(*)$, there exist scalars $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ such that
$$[{\bf w}]_B=\lambda_1[{\bf v}_1]_B+\cdots+\lambda_k[{\bf v}_k]_B\ .$$
By the lemma we have
$$[{\bf w}]_B=[\lambda_1{\bf v}_1+\cdots+\lambda_k{\bf v}_k]_B$$
and so
$${\bf w}=\lambda_1{\bf v}_1+\cdots+\lambda_k{\bf v}_k\ .$$
We have shown that any ${\bf w}$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$ can be written as a linear combination of ${\bf v}_1,\ldots,{\bf v}_k$, and so by definition, these vectors span ${\Bbb R}^n$.

Secondly, suppose that
$${\bf v}_1,\ldots,{\bf v}_k\quad\hbox{span}\quad {\Bbb R}^n\ ;\tag{$*{*}$}$$
we have to prove that $[{\bf v}_1]_B,\ldots,[{\bf v}_k]_B$ span ${\Bbb R}^n$.  So, let ${\bf x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be in ${\Bbb R}^n$ and write
$${\bf w}=x_1{\bf b}_1+\cdots+x_n{\bf b}_n\ .$$
By assumption $(*{*})$, there exist scalars $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ such that
$${\bf w}=\lambda_1{\bf v}_1+\cdots+\lambda_k{\bf v}_k\ .$$
Putting all these facts together, using the lemma and the definitions, we have
$$\eqalign{{\bf x}
  &=[{\bf w}]_B\cr
  &=[\lambda_1{\bf v}_1+\cdots+\lambda_k{\bf v}_k]_B\cr
  &=\lambda_1[{\bf v}_1]_B+\cdots+\lambda_k[{\bf v}_k]_B\ .\cr}$$
We have shown that any ${\bf x}$ in ${\Bbb R}^n$ can be written as a linear combination of $[{\bf v}_1]_B,\ldots,[{\bf v}_k]_B$, and so by definition, these vectors span ${\Bbb R}^n$.  This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\left[ \vec{x} \right]_B$ is the coordinate vector with respect to $\vec{x}$, here is a small hint. The map $\left[ \cdot \right]_B$ is *linear*, i.e., for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{v} , \vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$ \left[ \alpha \vec{v} + \vec{w} \right]_B = \alpha \left[ \vec{v} \right]_B + \left[ \vec{w} \right]_B $$

This should get you somewhere, if not, just comment and I can keep leading you in the right direction. The above equation is sometimes called the *Linearity of Coordinates*.

I might also help to know that $\left[ \cdot \right]_B$ is a one-to-one map.

Here is a edit to finish why the above works.

Let us assume the set of vectors $ \{ \vec{v}_i \} $ span $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for a vector $\vec{t} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have

$$ t = c_1 \vec{v}_1 + c_2 \vec{v}_2 + \cdots + c_n \vec{v}_n \; \; \; \; \; c_i \in \mathbb{R} $$

Then,

$$ \left[ \vec{t} \right]_B = \left[ c_1 \vec{v}_1 + c_2 \vec{v}_2 + \cdots + c_n \vec{v}_n \right]_B $$
$$ = c_1 \left[ \vec{v}_1 \right]_B + c_2 \left[ \vec{v}_2 \right]_B + \cdots + c_n \left[ \vec{v}_n \right]_B $$

where the equality comes from the linearity of coordinates. We see that for any arbitrary vector $\vec{t} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\left[ \vec{t} \right]_B$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $ \{ \left[ \vec{v}_i  \right]_B \}$ Thus, these span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

One can go further to proof that if $\{ \vec{v}_i \}$ are a basis, then so are $\{ \left[ \vec{v}_i \right]_B \}$.

Comment: This does not help.  A little too technical

Answer (score 0):

More generally, let $E$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the scalar field $F$, and let $(e_1, ..., e_n)$ be the canonic basis of $E$.

By definition, the vectors $(a_1, .., a_k)$ are called **linearly independent** if
$$
\forall (\lambda_1, .., \lambda_k)\in F^k,\quad \sum_i \lambda_i a_i = 0 \implies \lambda_i = 0\ \forall i \tag{1}
$$

Now let's assume that $(v_1,...,v_n)$ and $(b_1, ..., b_n)$ are both basis of $E$ (ie the subspace they generate is $E$, ie they "span" $E$). Each $v_k$ can be **decomposed** on the canonic basis $(e_1,..,e_n)$, meaning that it can be expressed as a **linear combination** of these vectors.

Now, if $(b_1,..., b_n)$ is a basis of $E$, then each $v_k$ can also be expressed as a linear combination of these vectors. This is what you wrote "$[v_k]_B$":
$$
\forall k,\quad \exists (\mu_{k,1}, ..., \mu_{k,n})\neq (0,...,0)\in F^n\ \big/\ v_k = [v_k]_B = \sum_i \mu_{k,i} b_i \tag{2}
$$

---

The proof then proceeds by showing that the family $([v_1]_B,...,[v_n]_B)$ is linearly independent, and since it is maximal (ie contains $n$ vectors in a vector space of dimension $n$) it forms a basis. To do that, let's assume that they are not linearly independent. Then by $(1)$, we could find $(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)\neq(0,...,0)$ such that
$$
\sum_k\lambda_k [v_k]_B = 0 = \sum_k\lambda_k \sum_i \mu_{k,i} b_i = \sum_i \left( \sum_k \lambda_k\mu_{k,i} \right) b_i
$$
which would mean that we found a null linear combination of $b_i$s, proving that they are not linearly independent, which contradicts our assumptions.

The reverse is exactly the same since we can swap $(b_1,...,b_n)$ with $(e_1,...,e_n)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand this proof.  I do not know what the variables you have are supposed to represent.

Comment: Clearer now? This is basic linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

So this might be a more appropriate solution given what you've learned, if you're doing a usual intro linear algebra course:

We know that a collection of vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,...,\mathbf{v}_k$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if the matrix $V = [\mathbf{v}_1 \; \mathbf{v}_2 \; ... \;\mathbf{v}_k]$ is *onto*, which means every equation of the form $V\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, where $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, has some solution $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Now, what about the vectors $[\mathbf{v}_1]_{B},[\mathbf{v}_2]_{B},...,[\mathbf{v}_k]_{B}$? We know that we can obtain a vector in $B$ coordinates by multiplying by a certain matrix, namely $[\mathbf{v}_i]_{B} = P_{B}^{-1}\mathbf{v}_i$, where $P_{B}$ denotes the matrix whose columns are the basis vectors in $B$. ($P_{B}$ is the 'change-of-coordinates' matrix).

It follows that the matrix $\tilde{V} = [[\mathbf{v}_1]_{B} \; [\mathbf{v}_2]_{B} \; ... \;[\mathbf{v}_k]_{B} ]$ is given by the equation $\tilde{V} = P_{B}^{-1}V$. You now need to show that $\tilde{V}$ is onto, so pick $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We want to solve the equation:

\begin{align}& \tilde{V}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b} \\
\Leftrightarrow & P_{B}^{-1}V\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b} \\
\Leftrightarrow & V\mathbf{x} = P_{B}\mathbf{b} \end{align}

We know that the last equation has a solution since $V$ is onto, which completes the proof.

Comment: I think using inverse matrices is a joke. If you're using the inverse matrix $P_B^{-1}$ it means you already know what an isomorphism is. If you already defined what an isomorphism is, then there is nothing to prove at all since the rank of $V$ is the rank of $\tilde{V}$. Logically speaking, you're using concepts that cannot be defined without the property that you're trying to prove, in order to prove this property. This is tautological. The question is basic, you have to use basic tools only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment- You're saying my argument is "Change of basis is an isomorphism" followed by "Isomorphisms preserve the rank of vectors", but then you claim that I can't define 'isomorphism' without the property that I'm trying to prove? I'm not sure I agree with that. An invertible matrix can be defined completely algebraically. It's not my favorite definition, but it's usually the first one students see.

Comment: Well I might be wrong, but before writing $P_B^{-1}$ as if it obviously made sense, I'd like to see how you could prove it exists without using a reasoning that could also prove that a change of basis preserves the rank (which is my understanding of the original question)?